# How to model volatility spillovers between some financial time series?

Tags: r, time-series, garch, finance, volatility

I am doing research to study volatility spillover effects between  several financial time series $\{x_{1,t}\}, \dots, \{x_{k,t}\}$ (in my case, $k=4$). What would be the best model to study the spillover effect of other series on $x_{1,t}$?

I was thinking of using VAR-GARCH or BEKK-GARCH Model in R. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is an edited copy of a thread that has been deleted. I repeatedly encounter similar questions, and the answer I gave in the deleted thread is relevant for many users. Therefore, I have copied the thread to preserve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**VAR**
VAR is a conditional mean model and as such has nothing to do with volatility spillovers – unless you apply it on realized variances instead of raw data. In that case it is a model that directly allows for volatility spillovers; see Diebold & Yilmaz ["Better to give than to receive: Predictive directional measurement of volatility spillovers"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016920701100032X) (2012).

**BEKK-GARCH**
Unfortunately, full BEKK-GARCH appears to be a nonsense model; see McAleer ["What They Did Not Tell You about Algebraic (Non-) Existence, Mathematical (IR-)Regularity and (Non-) Asymptotic Properties of the Full BEKK Dynamic Conditional Covariance Model"](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/12/2/66/htm) (2019). Diagonal BEKK-GARCH is fine, though (ibid.), but it does not seem to allow for volatility spillovers; see e.g. equations (6), (9) and (11) on p. 5 of Erten et al. ["Volatility Spillovers in Emerging Markets During the Global Financial Crisis: Diagonal BEKK Approach"](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/56190/1/MPRA_paper_56190.pdf) (2012) – even though people use it for the purpose (e.g. Zolfaghari et al. ["Volatility spillovers for energy prices: A diagonal BEKK approach"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140988320303054) (2020)).

**DCC-GARCH**
Some people use DCC-GARCH for the purpose, but that model does not allow for volatility spillovers by design (just like the diagonal BEKK-GARCH), as I have explained [elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/524457/interpretation-of-dccalpha-and-dccbeta-in-dcc-garch-model/524462#524462). Moreover, it is also full of problems: McAleer ["What They Did Not Tell You about Algebraic (Non-) Existence, Mathematical (IR-)Regularity, and (Non-) Asymptotic Properties of the Dynamic Conditional Correlation (DCC) Model"](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/12/2/61) (2019).

**Other models (e.g. GO-GARCH)**
There are other multivariate GARCH models out there, as reviewed in Bauwens et al. ["Multivariate GARCH models: a survey"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/jae.842) (2006) and Silvennoinen & Teräsvirta ["Multivariate GARCH models"](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/56218/1/538862637.pdf) (2009). Perhaps some of them might work. E.g. consider GO-GARCH; there are at least a couple of packages for estimating the model in R, namely, `gogarch` and `rmgarch`. <del>I am just afraid McAleer comes out soon and explains how GO-GARCH is full of problems, too :)</del>
<sub>[RIP Michael John McAleer](https://www.mdpi.com/2413-4155/3/4/48). The world of econometrics has lost a great man.</sub>